# Wrong redirection on passport.js google login

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have a problem with google auth using `passport.js`, sometimes I can register or login without a problem and sometimes I'm redirected to `/login` once I'm authenticated, the problem its on the middleware without it I don't have this problem.

I've set this passport google login strategy

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.google_consumer_key,
    clientSecret: config.google_consumer_secret,
    callbackURL: config.google_callback,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  async function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    await User.findOrCreate({ 
        email: profile.email, 
        username:`${profile.given_name} ${profile.family_name}` 
    },async function (err, user) {
      user.connected = true;
      await user.save();
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

and this routes to signin and the callback

```
router.get('/google-signin',
  passport.authenticate('google', 
    { scope:[ 'email', 'profile' ]}
));

router.get( '/google-callback',
    passport.authenticate( 'google', {failureRedirect: '/login'}),
    function(req,res){
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

On success the user is redirected to '/' and this route has a middleware, I checked `isAuthenticated` and it seems to be correct, but if doesn't work seems like its doesn't pass trough the middleware

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) 
      return res.redirect(301,'/login');
    return next();
};

  module.exports = isAuthenticated;
```

When it fails I'm redirected to '/login' with `304` code
[image]